# Yii Авторизация после регистрации.

Tags: php, yii, auth

Всем привет. Сделал регистрацию и авторизацию для Yii. После регистрации произвожу сразу авторизацию. Все происходит нормально, но тогда не удается получить данные пользователя (Например Yii::app()->user->getId() возвращает NULL). Достаточно разлогиниться и войти заново, тогда все данные появляются. Борюсь с этой проблемой уже сутки. Куда копать? За ранее спасибо.

Код UserIdentity:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    private $_username;
    private $_email;
    private $_firstname;
    private $_balance;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($record===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($record->password !== sha1($this->password . $record->salt))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
            $this->_id = $record->id;
            $this->_email = $record->email;
            $this->_firstname = $record->firstname;

            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->_username;
    }
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->_email;
    }
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->_firstname;
    }

}
```

Код actionSignup:

```
public function actionSignup()
    {
        if(!yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
            $this->redirect($this->createUrl('panel/'));
        }

        $model = new User(User::SCENARIO_SIGNUP);

        if(isset($_POST['User']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
            $model->verifyCode = $_POST['User']['verifyCode'];

            if($model->validate())
            {
                $model->save(false);

                /* $identity = new UserIdentity($model->username, $model->password);
                $identity->authenticate();*/

                $identity = new UserIdentity($model->username, $model->password);
                $identity->authenticate();
                Yii::app()->user->login($identity);

                $this->redirect($this->createUrl('panel/'));
            }
        }

        $this->render('signup', array('model' => $model));
    }
```

Comment: Поставьте if ($identity->autheticate()). Не вижу повода аутентификации проваливаться в данном случае, но других явно подозрительных мест нет.

Comment: @Fike, Добавил условие if ($identity->autheticate()) — теперь регистрация вообще работает неправильно. Регистрация происходит, пользователь создается, страница никуда не редиректит, ошибка не выводится, форма остается заполненной, только сильно увеличивается число символов в пароле (в поле ввода).

Comment: Значит ошибка в коде... нужно врубить показ всех ошибок и смотреть + логи приложения смотреть.

Comment: я имел в виду не просто if добавить, а разветвить действие и посмотреть, проходит ли аутентификация сразу после регистрации. Смысл метода authenticate в том, что он пытается аутентифицировать пользователя (эта часть включает в себя произвольный код) и возвращает true или false в зависимости от того, удалось ли аутентифицировать пользователя. Посмотрите, какой errorCode стоит у $identity после попытки аутентификации.

Comment: @Fike, в таком случае возвращает false;

Comment: КОД ОБНОВИ! Мы тут в догадки играть будем чтоли?

Comment: @Nick, я говорю - смотрите errorCode, по нему определяйте, где у вас проблема.

Ставлю бутылку пива на то, что $model->password у вас в момент аутентификации не cам пароль, а его хеш в том виде, в котором он записывается в БД, поэтому проверка по паролю и не проходит.

Comment: ...либо вообще пустой, но, думаю, проблема именно в этом несоответствии.

Comment: @Fike — Вы совершенно правы) Именно в шифровке пароля проблема была) Уже передается в $model->password зашифрованный пароль. Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НУ получаешь из формы данные. проверяешь их, если гуд то хорошо.
Записываешь юзера в БД, ну а дальше его авторизуешь

```
$identity=new UserIdentity($form->attributes['email'],$nonemd5);
   if($identity->authenticate()){
      Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
      $this->redirect("/profile/user");
    }
```

Ну и все. что сложного?

Comment: в коде автора вообще-то есть эти строчки, разве что без ифа. Но "записываешь юзера в бд ... дальше его авторизуешь" там есть.

Comment: Ну разница то в коде есть, есть. ТС просто не внимательный, вот и все.

Но я бы еще добавил 

if ( $model->save() )  // начать авторизацию

Comment: еще раз, у автора ошибка не в том, что он не аутентифицирует пользователя после регистрации

Comment: Если код не работает, но написан - это не значит что он правильный!

Comment: в третий раз: автор НЕ забыл об аутентификации, у него ошибка в другом месте.